# XML parsing for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Cant we creat a object for XmlDocument in Visual studio 2012 for mobile,
The code is as shown

```
string url1 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=bangalore&sensor=false";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@url1);
XmlNode MyNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat");        
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("lat: ", MyNode.InnerText));
```

Comment: And what is your question? You can also use the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class which is more preferred that XmlDocument

Comment: its throwing me a error for using XmlDocument.Its working fine on Visual Studio Express 2013 for desktop but not on visual studio Express 2012 for windows phone

Answer (score 0):

It seems that XmlDocument is not supported in Windows Phone 8. But you can use the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class instead.

I have updated your code to use the XDocument class and the extension method [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb156083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the required node. You will need to set the required namespaces in your code.

```
string url1 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=bangalore&sensor=false";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url1);

XElement myNode = doc.XPathSelectElement("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat");        
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("lat: ", myNode.Value));
```

If the XPathSelectElement-Extension method is not available you can use the Element()-Method on XElement.

```
XElement myNode = doc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result").Element("geometry").Element("location").Element("lat");
```

Comment: Thanks Jehof,But it throw's error saying that XPathSelectElement() method not found,Kindly help.

Comment: Yeah,But am getting an exception as follow  "An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll" @ line XDocument.Load() method,Please Help,Sorry for troubling you